# Can I use a mono library from Objective-C (on the iPhone)?

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, mono

I am investigating a port of an app to the iPhone. My existing business logic is C# in a class library dll. It does some processing as well as sommunicating with web sites.

I understand that Objective-C is the best thing to develop with on the iPhone and I'm prepared to dive in, but if possible I want to avoid re-writing the existing logic code.

If I rework the .NET library in mono (assuming that is possible), is there a way of using the mono output from Objective-C on the iPhone?

Any hints welcome!

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the static compilation feature of Mono to develop C# for the iPhone.  Here is a link to some details on how to accomplish this

- http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/01/open-source-mono-framework-brings-c-to-iphone-and-wii.ars

Answer (score 1):

This appears to provide the ability to load a CLR assembly and call into it from Objective-C:

- http://mono-project.com/ObjCSharp